# Python Selenium 'module' object is not callable error. using select method

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
dob = 12

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.avant.com/apply")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
month = select(driver.find_element(By.ID, 'person_date_of_birth_month'))

if dob == 12:
    month.selectByVisbleText('Jan')
```

I am trying to select from the Month Of Birth drop box on the site [www.avant.com/apply](http://www.avant.com/apply). so that if the users input is the 12th month it will select January but i am getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dee\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\main.py", line 16, in <module>
    month = select(driver.find_element(By.ID, 'person_date_of_birth_month'))
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: Maybe using .click() method instead of select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code works perfectly in my machine, check and tweak your code accordingly:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

dob = 12
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.avant.com/apply")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
month = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, 'person_date_of_birth_month'))

if dob == 12:
    month.select_by_visible_text('Jan')
```

Output for your reference:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i think your select should be Select (uppercase)

try it out and see

```
dob = 12

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.avant.com/apply")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
month = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, 'person_date_of_birth_month'))

if dob == 12:
    month.select_by_visible_text('Jan')
```